# SQL Query for non duplicate items only

Tags: sql

I'm attempting to build a query to only retrieve only unique records on a table.  I would like to pull all info from the table using `Select *`.

For example I would like to do Select * from Bin, and only show records that DO NOT have a duplicate value in 1 specific column.

Example of result for `Select * from Bin` (it returns a lot more columns, but you get the idea)

| Station | MyNo | Item | Qty | Max | Min |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 77 | 1-A | 1234 | 10 | 10 | 5 |
| 77 | 1-B | 1234 | 2 | 4 | 1 |
| 77 | 1-C | 5432 | 5 | 8 | 2 |
| 77 | 1-D | 2851 | 18 | 20 | 8 |
| 77 | 1-E | 9432 | 24 | 25 | 15 |

And would like to instead retreive:

| Station | MyNo | Item | Qty | Max | Min |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 77 | 1-C | 5432 | 5 | 8 | 2 |
| 77 | 1-D | 2851 | 18 | 20 | 8 |
| 77 | 1-E | 9432 | 24 | 25 | 15 |

`SELECT DISTINCT` will not work, as I do not want to retrieve anything that has a duplicate value in the "Item" field.  I'm not sure if HAVING COUNT would work, but have not been able to get HAVING COUNT to work for me.

I hope this makes sense with how I explained it.
I'm currently using SQL Server Management Studio 18.
I am fairly new to SQL so I appreciate any help I can get.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks for the advice!  I've updated my post, so hopefully this works better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simple query to show all column with items not in duplicates value

```
select item ,STRING_AGG([Station], ',') as [Station] ,STRING_AGG([MyNo], ',') as [MyNo] ,STRING_AGG([Qty], ',') as [Qty] ,STRING_AGG([Max], ',') as [Max]  ,STRING_AGG([Min], ',') as [Min] from Bin group by item  having count(*) = 1
```

Comment: Thank you!  this one seems to work for what I need.  Question on this query, there's no way to 'Select * '?  I would have to manually add all column headers in order to retrieve the full table right?

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `COUNT()` function here as a window function:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Item) cnt
    FROM Bin
)

SELECT Station, MyNo, Item, Qty, Max, Min
FROM cte
WHERE cnt = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

A **subquery** containing those duplicate records is another option to solve this problem.

```
select * from Bin
where item not in 
    (select item from Bin group by item having count(*) > 1)
```